# String parameter conditions

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to call a method that adds a space to a `string`.

So, because I'm changing the length of `string`, I assume that I can't do something like `addSpace("hello world");`, instead I have to define it as `char word[100] = "hello world"` and then `addSpace(word)`. But I have so many cases, that this is going to take up a lot of space, so is there another way to just have the sentence in the `string` parameter even when I have to change it?

Comment: can you provide an example? i'm afraid an accurate answer will depend on from where do those strings come from

Answer (score 2):

If you call a function like that: `addSpace("hello world");` modifying the parameter inside the function is undefined behavior. Instead you can make a copy of the parameter and return that:

```
char* addSpace(const char* str) {
    char* copy = malloc(strlen(str) + 2); // +1 for space, +1 for null terminator
    if (copy != 0) {
        // code to copy str to copy and add space
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Just remember to `free` the returned pointer afterwards, and error check the return value.